# How to change my the date format in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have

```
  num4 = xlsread('dat.xlsx', 1, 'A:B');
  dnum4=datetime(num4(:,1),1,1) + caldays(num4(:,2));

dnum4= 
   16-Jul-2008
   18-Jul-2008
   06-Aug-2008
   08-Aug-2008
   13-Aug-2008
   15-Aug-2008
   20-Aug-2008
   22-Aug-2008
   30-Oct-2008
```

I want to change the outputs from `dd-mmm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`.
How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime-properties.html) you'll see that `datetime` objects have a `Format` property that controls the display format:

```
>> t = datetime('now','TimeZone','local','Format','d-MMM-y HH:mm:ss Z')

t = 

  datetime

   25-May-2017 10:26:46 -0400


>> t.Format = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

t = 

  datetime

   2017-05-25
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to convert to datenum, then back to datestr:

```
newFmt = datestr(datenum(dnum4, 'dd-mmm-yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: Thank you, but it got errors:

Error using datetime/datenum
Too many input arguments.

Error in (line 25)
newFmt = datestr(datenum(dnum, 'dd-mmm-yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Comment: That's because you need to deal with one data after another rather than passing it an entire array of dates. Use a for loop to go through each one.
By the way did you ask a question that got deleted? Was to do with the day of the year..

Comment: Passing all (char array or cell) works for me. Maybe it is Matlab version difference?

Comment: @scotty3785 that's not at all true. The documentation very clearly states that both `datestr` and `datenum` accept arrays of values.

Comment: I stand corrected. What's the fix for this answer then?